# Python subprocess Popen returns with non zero error code but no error

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to execute an executable binary that produces an error. My code for the execution of binary using Popen:

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = p.communicate()
return_code = p.returncode
if error:
   raise SomeLocallyDefinedError
```

This is supposed to raise error when the script execution results in an error. The cmd in this particular case is the path to the concerned executable binary.

Now when I execute this very binary on my terminal ./binary_file it gives me an error msg

"Floating point exception: 8".

**But when the script is executed by Popen , there is no error as well as output. But the returncode is -8. I believe that a non zero return code implies an error and if so why was the message not captured by Popen.communicate()?**

In case you guys are wondering what was the executable binary file. The binary file was generated by a compiling a c file that results in run time error. Here is the content of c file

```
# include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int a = 18;
   int b = 0;
   int c = a/b;
   printf("%d", c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is generated by the shell, while catching an `SIGFPE` signal. You have to catch this signal in your program by yourself and handle it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This is not just an ordinary runtime error, it is a process crash raised by kernel (via a signal).

If you are running on UNIX//Linux/OS X you should get a core dump (`ulimit -c unlimited` in the shell). Kernel does not write to a process's stderr - it can't because the process has crashed.

This is not an issue with Python.